# empty multiple session files

Tags: php, session, google-chrome

I have a problem with Chrome + Sessions...

Usually user logins to the system and two session files are created (why 2 I have no idea, is that normal?)

```
-rw-------  1 x x 8478 Jul 11 22:59 sess_6ddd3db26f98a678ed0a56a058653d56
-rw-------  1 x x    0 Jul 11 22:58 sess_ccab7f6ede0bb7635814adfd5b48332a
```

Then 6ddd is used through the system and everything is cool.

However when user is using Chrome 3 files are created:

```
-rw-------  1 x x    0 Jul 11 23:00 sess_165378d6d663752ad72e198ad79c7d03
-rw-------  1 x x    0 Jul 11 23:00 sess_58a0e8bd77bfe15d7531675653f36c15
-rw-------  1 x x    0 Jul 11 23:00 sess_bc9ae9c92644d39b29751a157053b7c8
```

and then bc9 file is used - which is empty - all of them are...

Now my question is - is this application that is screwed up or is this a php configuration issue? Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I found the code that was multiplying session and chopped it off. Now I get 1 fiel per session and its not empty any more.

However there is still an issue of session fields being different when opening page in Chrome.

Firs file is session from Firefox, second is from Chrome...

```
-rw-------  1 x x 8363 Jul 11 23:38 sess_6a44293683a90696aa43b0ce64cec790
-rw-------  1 x x 16722 Jul 11 23:39 sess_ce9e4a3e1ed11ee4d8b5171ce1ad4f92
```

Now, why am I asking about PHP configuration... well same system runs on several servers, and only one has a problem. On others - everything works flawlessly (even with those multiple session files). On this one session does not store vital information and logs people out. An only in Chrome.

Hence my question here - I would like to rule out possible php configuration problems before I spend a day digging through this horrible code only to learn later that it was a settings issue. As I say it works on 5 servers and fails on one. And only started failing a week ago - and this is a server that is managed by a customer himself so perhaps they did something to the server that causes it work differently for Chrome and other browsers.

PS. Besides I really do not understand why do you put answers as comments, guys. This way I have no way of accepting an answer even if I like it!

Comment: `is this application that is screwed up` - yes. Sessions should create one file and one file only, behaviour should be same the across all browsers. Something is not right about the way the cookies are being set. Off the top of my head I'm struggling to think of an explanation as to why this is happening. I think we'll need to see your session handling code, and if you are able/happy to point us to your live development server where this is happening that would be useful.

Comment: session file = session. if you get multiple session files, then multipl sessions are being created, which usually means the session cookie settings are wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for anyone experiencing similar problem:

System was on a shared hosting server. Some configuration was incorrect - I am not sure what exactly was wrong, but placing a .htaccess with

```
RewriteBase /main_app_folder
```

Fixed this issue. I have no clue why RewriteBase affected sessions but it did. Glad it's fixed :).